# Dividing/Organizing a list of tuples

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples that have the form of (s{i}, g{j}, {n}). I am looking to create a nested list or dictionary, organized by their first and second value, with the third value being optional for what sorting. What I have gotten so far is:

```
l = [("s1", "g1", "1), ("s1", "g2", 2), ("s1", "g2", 1), ("s1", "g2", 2), ("s2", "g1", 1), ("s2", "g1", 2), ("s2", "g2", 1), ("s2", "g2", 2)]
```

The result I would like is

```
l = [
        [
            [("s1", "g1", "1),("s1", "g2", 2)],
            [("s1", "g2", 1),("s1", "g2", 2)]
        ],
        [
            [("s2", "g1", 1),("s2", "g1", 2)],
            [("s2", "g2", 1),("s2", "g2", 2)]
        ]  
    ]
```

So how would I go about this sort of indexing?

Edit: Apologies, added quotations to indicate they were strings and not variables and the way I asked the question. I am relatively new to coding so forgive my transgressions.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Maybe something like [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) would be worth looking at.

Comment: PLs post code that can be copied and used. What is `s1`, `g`, etc...?

Comment: After the words "What I have tried so far is:", you are supposed to post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and `operator.itemgetter` to make this less boilerplate-y:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

k1 = itemgetter(0)
k2 = itemgetter(1)

def sortgroup(data, key):
    return groupby(sorted(data, key=key), key=key)

l = [[[*g2] for _, g2 in sortgroup(g1, k2)] for _, g1 in sortgroup(l, k1)]
[[[('s1', 'g1', 1), ('s1', 'g1', 2)], 
  [('s1', 'g2', 1), ('s1', 'g2', 2)]], 
 [[('s2', 'g1', 1), ('s2', 'g1', 2)], 
  [('s2', 'g2', 1), ('s2', 'g2', 2)]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I propose.
The general idea is to build first a dictionary of dictionaries where the first dictionary has the primary key which is the first element in your list of tuples and inside this value is another dictionary where the key is the second element of the tuple and to this value in the second dictionary is associated a list with the values of the third position in your tuple.

```
l = [("s1", "g1", 1), ("s1", "g1", 2), ("s1", "g2", 1), ("s1", "g2", 2), ("s2", "g1", 1), ("s2", "g1", 2), ("s2", "g2", 1), ("s2", "g2", 2)] 


val = dict()
for tup in l:
    if tup[0] not in val:
        val[tup[0]]= {tup[1]:[tup[2]]}
    else:
        if tup[1] in val[tup[0]]:
            val[tup[0]][tup[1]].append(tup[2])
        else:
            val[tup[0]][tup[1]]=[tup[2]]

print("-----------------------------")
print("The dictionary built is")
print(val)
print("-----------------------------")
print("===============The result is=========================")

final_list = []
for first_key in val.keys():
    list_temp = []
    for second_key in val[first_key].keys():
        list_temp2 = []
        for val_list in val[first_key][second_key]:
           list_temp2.append((first_key,second_key,val_list))
        list_temp.append(list_temp2)
    final_list.append(list_temp)
print(final_list)
print("========================================")
```

The output is:

```
-----------------------------
The dictionary built is
{'s1': {'g1': [1, 2], 'g2': [1, 2]}, 's2': {'g1': [1, 2], 'g2': [1, 2]}}
-----------------------------
===============The result is=========================
[[[('s1', 'g1', 1), ('s1', 'g1', 2)], [('s1', 'g2', 1), ('s1', 'g2', 2)]], [[('s2', 'g1', 1), ('s2', 'g1', 2)], [('s2', 'g2', 1), ('s2', 'g2', 2)]]]
========================================
```